# UWP Combo Box values dynamically generates text boxes

Tags: c#, uwp, combobox, uwp-xaml, dynamically-generated

I have a combo box populated with integers. If I choose three, I want to show 3 text boxes next to it. If I choose 2, I want to show 2.
In text boxes I write sample numbers: 123, 943, 1e4, etc. Simply strings.

**file.xaml**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.SamplesCountList, Mode=OneTime}" 
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SamplesCount, Mode=TwoWay}" />

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.SamplesCollection, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I use MVVM Light. I have a ViewModel which has a Model from Business Layer. `SamplesCollection`  is linked to `ItemsControl`. If I update the observable list, it generates dynamically text boxes. Which is good.

**viewmodel.cs**

```
public class MyModelViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
    private MyModelModel _myModelModel = new MyModelModel();
    public MyModelModel MyModelModel
    {
        get { return _myModelModel; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _myModelModel, value); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> SamplesCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public CreateFile() {
        // Take _myModelModel and create text file based on its fields
    }

}
```

In other parts, I simply link my business model directly with a text box in the xaml.
Like this
`ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=MyViewModel.MyModel.Id, Mode=TwoWay}`
I cannot do this with this dynamic ItemsControl<->ComboBox since it does not detect changes to create text boxes, because
`ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=MyViewModel.MyModel.SamplesCollectionModel}`
, `SamplesCollectionModel` is a `List<string>` in Business Layer.

Question: Should I just take my observable SamplesCollection.ToList() and assign it to my _myModel whenever I need to process it, or can I link my business model with the xaml code somehow to get rid of this additional field of observable collection? What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you do the work in the ViewModel instead of trying to change the business model. This is because you are using MVVM pattern and the model layer should just keep your business data.

For more information, please check: [Data binding and MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-and-mvvm).

**Update:**

@Mihai Socaciu found the Github sample here:
[Windows-appsample-customers-orders-database](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-appsample-customers-orders-database/blob/33e06db8b0ce2eee5a55f757677f7670a8c4bda5/ContosoApp/ViewModels/OrderViewModel.cs). It contains a solution for such a scenario and all the detailed code are listed there.

Basically the code looks like this:

```
public class OrderViewModel 
{
    private ObservableCollection<LineItem> _lineItems;

    public ObservableCollection<LineItem> LineItems 
    {
        get => _lineItems;
        set
        {
            if (_lineItems != value)
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    value.CollectionChanged += LineItems_Changed;
                }

                if (_lineItems != null)
                {
                    _lineItems.CollectionChanged -= LineItems_Changed;
                }
                _lineItems = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public OrderViewModel()
    {
        LineItems = new ObservableCollection<LineItem>(Model.LineItems);
        LineItems.CollectionChanged += LineItems_Changed;
    }

    private void LineItems_Changed(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (LineItems != null)
        {
            Model.LineItems = LineItems.ToList();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That link sent me to this project `https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-customers-orders-database` which showed me exactly the answer in `OrderViewModel`.
Solution:
Write in ViewModel an observable collection and link it with Model's List<string> in the constructor.
```
LineItems = new ObservableCollection<LineItem>(Model.LineItems);
LineItems.CollectionChanged += LineItems_Changed;
```
Can you please append this to your answer, so I can check solution.

Comment: @MihaiSocaciu Sure, I'll update my answer with the sample and share some simple code snippet about the solution.